# How to make a function that can only be executed on one thread simultaneously?

Tags: c++, multithreading, simultaneous

I have a program that i am using to find prime numbers. it is executing on multiple threads. I am using the GetNextNumber() function for the threads to call to get a number to check if it is prime, however it seems that this function is being executed simultaneously by more than 1 thread, so sometimes two threads get the same number. here is my code:

```cpp
#include "pch.h"
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int nextInt = 1;
std::ofstream file;

bool TestPrime(int number)
{
    double rootInt = sqrt(number);
    for (int i = 3; i <= rootInt; i += 2)
    {
        double divValue = (double)number / i;
        if (int(divValue) == divValue)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
int GetNextNumber()
{
    return (nextInt += 2);
}

void PrimeFinderThread()
{
    while (true)
    {
        int number = GetNextNumber();
        bool isPrime = TestPrime(number);
        if (isPrime)
        {
            std::string fileOutput = std::to_string(number) + "-";
            file << fileOutput;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    file.open("primes.txt", std::ofstream::app);
    file << 2 << "-";
    std::thread threads[4];
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        threads[i] = std::thread(PrimeFinderThread);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        threads[i].join();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use a [std::mutex](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex)

Comment: That's what synchronization primitives like `std::mutex` are for.

Comment: You should learn about [critical sections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_section). A mutex is the mechanism to solve this issue.

Comment: For me this is [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). You have some performance issue and you have decided to solve it by using multi-threading (and you ask to fix that part), when inf act problem is naive implementation of prime number checking. In fact accepted answer doesn't fix all multi threading issues. Describe precisely problem this code should solve.

Comment: please read [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [std::mutex](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex) with [std::lock_guard](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard). It will prevent simultaneous execution of the function.

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <mutex>

int nextInt = 1;
std::ofstream file;

bool TestPrime(int number)
{
    double rootInt = sqrt(number);
    for (int i = 3; i <= rootInt; i += 2)
    {
        double divValue = (double)number / i;
        if (int(divValue) == divValue)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
int GetNextNumber()
{
    static std::mutex m;
    const std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m);
    return (nextInt += 2);
}

void PrimeFinderThread()
{
    while (true)
    {
        int number = GetNextNumber();
        bool isPrime = TestPrime(number);
        if (isPrime)
        {
            std::string fileOutput = std::to_string(number) + "-";
            file << fileOutput;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    file.open("primes.txt", std::ofstream::app);
    file << 2 << "-";
    std::thread threads[4];
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        threads[i] = std::thread(PrimeFinderThread);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        threads[i].join();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: FYI this is still wrong. There is race condition on `file`.

Comment: and you have broken his code. By mistake you have deleted `if` statement - fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Using a mutex is a valid solution, but in this case it causes unnecessary overhead. You can simply make `nextId` atomic:

```
std::atomic<int> nextId{1};
```

This makes the increment operation in `GetNextNumber` atomic, so no two threads will get the same value.

Comment: There is also race condition on `file`.

Comment: Good point - I was focused on the `GetNextNumber` and completely missed that.